# send text from combobox c# form as a input of procedure SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, combobox

i'm stuck at a problem from my code. I have a database in SQL and two table named: Categories and Produces. i've already created a procedure named: viewByCat, this procedure will show for me all produces of one Category when i choose what kind of Categories i want to show in combobox. For example: i have clothes, shoes, cats in combobox, when i choose "clothes" => it will show for me all clothes have stored in Produces. how can i pass a text of combobox as input of procedure, take a look at my code:

## SQL

```
create proc viewByCat 
@keywords nvarchar(30)
as
select PD.ProID , PD.ProName , PD.TinyDes ,PD.FullDes ,PD.Price ,PD.CatID ,PD.Quantity 
from Categories CT join Products PD on CT.CatID = PD.CatID 
where CT.CatName = @keywords
go
```

## C-sharp

```
  private void btn_viewByCategories_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //initialize source will be displayed on dgv
        List<Produce> src_produces = new List<Produce>();
        //create SqlConnection
        //create connection
        string connectionstring = @"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=sellingManager;integrated security=true";
        //create SqlConnection with above string
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            //create SqlCommand
            SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
            //use SqlCommand to present for procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //invoke procedure will be used
            cmd.CommandText = "viewByCat";
            //open connection
            cnn.Open();
            //
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
             //something...
            }
```

Comment: You can pass parameter value to stored procedure like below cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@keywords",dropdownselectecteditem);

Comment: @user2173966 it can't understand dropdownselectecteditem

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your C# code. Please refer following code:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("viewByCat]", connectionstring);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@keywords", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value ="Your Selected value from combo box";


        cnn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sdadptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sdadptr.Fill(dt);
        }
        cnn.Close();
        return dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html) instead of SQLConnection and SQLCommand respectively.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "viewByCat";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywords", ComboBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters["@keywords"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
MySqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
    }
}
finally
{
    myReader.Close();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameter with your SP.

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

                if (cnn.State.ToString() == "Closed") cnn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("viewByCat", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@keywords", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Combobox.Text;

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds, "Search");

                cnn.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add following statement in your C# code.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywords", YourComboBoxId.SelectedItem.Text);
 cmd.Parameters["@keywords"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Modify 'YourComboBoxId' with actual combo box id value. I hope this will solve your problem .